# How to apply Coordinator design pattern to MVP based projects?

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp, android-mvp, coordinator-pattern

I've been working on a project that uses MVP as an architecture pattern. And also, we're using the Navigator design pattern for Activity/Fragment navigation. That was helpful to extract navigation logic to a more observable class but it still is not observable and modular as we expected because we want to observe the flow more independently rather going to X Navigator. Then I was reading an article about Coordinator pattern on Android and how to solve these issues. But the post was based on MVVM and I couldn't grasp the idea of how to apply on MVP based project. Are there any beneficial resources that you know about it because I couldn't find it? Or an explanation would be more than welcome. Thanks.

[Here is the article about Coordinators](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/coordinators-android)